# Mathematica crashes with non-integer exponents using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, crash

I want to solve a system of coupled PDEs. It works fine if I set $i=0.$ ($i$ is in the exponent of the PDEs) or $i=1.$ in the code. However, if I set, e.g., $i=0.1$ NDSolve crashes after a few seconds. Why is this? How can I avoid that? I tried the same with smooth initical conditions with the same result.

Thank you very much for any comments. Here is the code:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
lo = 23;
hi = 27;
domlen = 50;
ic11[x_]:=Piecewise[{{6,lo<x<hi},{0,True}}];
ic21[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1/2,lo<x<hi},{1/c11,True}}];

bc = {z[t, 0] == ic11[0], z[t, domlen] == ic11[domlen], 
pp[t, 0] == ic21[0], pp[t, domlen] == ic21[domlen]};

eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732;
tfin = 100;
i=0.1;

pde11 := 
D[pp[t, x], t] == 
 1.*Laplacian[pp[t, x], {x}] + 
  pp[t, x]*(1. - c11*pp[t, x] - 
     z[t, x]/(1. + pp[t, x]^(1. + i)));
pde21 := 
 D[z[t, x], t] == 
  1.*Laplacian[z[t, x], {x}] + 
   z[t, x]*(eps*pp[t, x]/(1. + pp[t, x]^(1. + i)) - m);

sol1d = NDSolve[{pde11, pde21, bc, z[0, x] == ic11[x], 
  pp[0, x] == ic21[x]}, {pp, z}, {t, 0, tfin}, {x, 0, domlen}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDSolve is running out of memory. This may have something to do with the solver having to change from real to complex numbers during the computation. When I tried to use the finite element method I got the following message:

```
sol1d = NDSolve[{pde11, pde21, bc, z[0, x] == ic11[x], 
   pp[0, x] == ic21[x]}, {pp, z}, {t, 0, tfin}, {x, 0, domlen}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]

NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

I then changes the initial conditions to return complex values to hint the solver to do the time integration with complex numbers:

```
ic11[x_] := Piecewise[{{6 + 0. I, lo < x < hi}, {0 + 0. I, True}}];
ic21[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1/2 + 0. I, lo < x < hi}, {1/c11 + 0. I, True}}];
```

This then NDSolve solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a nice trick and it works. I am not 100% yet whether it has some impact on the results, but so far it looks fine.